# CSS Media query not working on mobile devices whereas fine with desktop

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, emotion

I'm in the making of responsive web page using emotion.js styled components. 
On Desktop emulator using Chrome, it looks perfectly fine [as I meant it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGz9F.png) but when on [mobile web inspector screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbc8V.png) shows me that media query is not showing.
I tried every single duplicated question on S/O, none of them work for my case.

My meta tag seems okay like this
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />`, 
also tried with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` got me the same result.

FYI I use github pages for deployment.

[EDIT]

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                    <div className="App">
                        <Home />
                        <AnimatedCursor color="0,198,171" innerSize={20} outerSize={20} />
                    </div>
                }
            />
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import Intro from './Intro';
import Outro from './Outro';
import Profile from './Profile';
import TechStack from './TechStack';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Intro />
            <Profile />
            <TechStack />
            <Outro />
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

**Cover.jsx**

```
const Cover = styled.div`
    font-family: Cover;
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: #005b96;
    @media (${devices.mobileL}) {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
`;
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant code otherwise we will just be guessing. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I attached the code snippets as requested. Please take a look.

Comment: It seems to be compiling with double brackets around the media test. Try putting the @media outside, not nested.

Comment: @AHaworth Now finally it works. Thank you !

Comment: @saltvine make sure to mark this question as answered or closed!